# How would you locate the missing angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, geometry

I recently took a quiz on Vectors and had issues with this particular problem. I believe the Vector will be located in quadrant 3 and thought the answer was D. How would you locate the missing angle?

[image]

Comment: Just draw it out. The question does seem a tad ambiguous since it doesn't state the angle convention to be used.

Comment: @DKNguyen When I initially did the quiz I was stuck between B. and D. I believe I eventually put B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $A_x<0,$ $A$ will not lie in first or fourth quadrant.
As $A_y<0$ $A$ will not lie in first or second quadrant.
$\implies A $ will lie in third quadrant.

Comment: Thanks, when I took the Quiz I was stuck between D. & B. I believe I chose B and was marked wrong.